# Creating titles while editing posts

Tags: discussion, edits

I've been working the review queue lately, and editing posts that really need it. One of them was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36780613/revisions), whose title was originally

> I am trying to import a PFX file into a JKS . I am executing the below command and getting the below error

Which is really not much of a title, and is better suited to the body of the question. I edited it, but realized that this meant that the post no longer had a title; so I created one which I thought reflected the body and content of the question:

> Illegal option error when importing JKS keystore with keytool

My edit was accepted, but I'm still a little uncomfortable with this, and would like clarification - is it acceptable to create a new title for an edited post out of whole cloth, based entirely on one's understanding of what OP is trying to ask?

Comment: Bear in mind that: 1. Your edits will get reviewed; and 2. The author can revert or edit further if needed. If you're getting accepted, don't feel uncomfortable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe *" If you're getting accepted, don't feel uncomfortable"* ideally, yes. But with the robo-reviewers I still think it's good to ask here if someone isn't sure about something. Otherwise, good points. I will just add that it is fine to rework/rewrite the title as long as you feel you can make it more specific and relevant by understanding what the OP really wants to ask. I've done it often to titles like "This doesn't work cuz errors"

Comment: Yes, it's totally acceptable to improve titles - and to make up new ones completely if the previous title was horrible.

Comment: The user first posted [Import PFX file into JKS file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36753560/1529630) and that text was in the body of the post. Then he deleted it and asked this very similar question, moving the text to title in the process.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> This meant that the post no longer had a title

Were it true, this would be a strong indicator that the post itself is highly localised, will be of no use to anyone in the future, and can safely be closed/deleted.

However, in this case, you *did* find a good title for the question, and correctly edited it in.

Good job!